# Writing special characters to the clipboard with the command line

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, copy-paste

I'm trying to write the string `あいうえお` to my clipboard using the [pbcopy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html) command line tool like this

```
echo あいうえお | pbcopy
```

But what I'm getting in my clipboard is completely different : `„ÅÇ„ÅÑ„ÅÜ„Åà„Åä`.

I assumed this had something to do with the encoding, but the documentation says the encoding is based on the LANG environment variable and mine is set to `en_EN.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your `LANG=en_EN.UTF-8` is the problem.

When I execute this command

```
printf あいうえお | LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 pbcopy
```

and paste into a new *TextEdit* document I get `„ÅÇ„ÅÑ„ÅÜ„Åà„Åä` (incidentally, this is what you get if take the the UTF-8 encoding of your original text and decode it as MacRoman; you should be able to verify this by doing `printf あいうえお | iconv -f macroman`).

When I execute this command

```
printf あいうえお | LANG=en_US.UTF-8 pbcopy
```

and paste into a new *TextEdit* document I get `あいうえお`, just as one would expect.

---

I am pretty sure that `en_EN.UTF-8` is not a valid locale (thus `pbcopy` is defaulting to MacRoman). Maybe you meant to use `en_US.UTF-8` (i.e. `US`, not `EN`)? You can list the valid locales by running `locale -a`. If you are just interested in English UTF-8 locales, you can filter the list like this:

```
locale -a | grep '^en_.*\.UTF-8$'
```

Comment: Well that worked. I dunno why my LANG was en_EN instead of en_US. Didn't even realize that could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely its your Terminal. Enter the command `locale` and see what it says there. If it doesn't list some Japanese encoding, that's probably what it is. Also, try selecting "Unicode (UTF-8)" as the Character encoding from Preferences..., Settings, Advanced, International. Also play around with Preferences / Encodings, enabling the Japanese encodings (is that Japanese? idk! LOL).

Also make sure to set `LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"` in your .bash_profile if it doesn't appear when you use the `locale` command.